# Streamline code for checking if a directory exists and saving a file

Tags: c#, strings, file-system

I hate this code.  What is the slickest way to write the following:

```
MyFile = f;
SaveFolder = Server.MapPath("\\") + "returns\\";
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(SaveFolder) )
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveFolder);
}
MyFile.SaveAs(SaveFolder + "2011" + "000-00-0000" + ".xlsx");
```

Comment: What exactly do you hate about this code? Are you looking for a 1-line version of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `CreateDirectory` does nothing if a directory already exists, you can do this:

```
MyFile = f;
SaveFolder = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"), "returns");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveFolder);
MyFile.SaveAs(SaveFolder, "2011000-00-0000.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 6):

well, for starters, use Path.Combine... eg :-

```
SaveFolder = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"\"),"returns");
```

same kind of thing for building your file name.

Comment: I'm not using 4.0

Comment: Thats ok, they were nice enough to build it into .NET since 1.1 I think

Comment: It's burried in under System.IO :)

Comment: You may be right.  However, check out Microsoft's own documentation..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx  It only lists .Net 4.0 & Silverlight  I googled this BEFORE, I posted that I wasn't using 4.0

Comment: @MVCylon msdn isn't maybe that clear about it, but the trick is, only one Combine override was available pre .Net 4 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.80).aspx that's why you could choose it